# What is n in the for loop that begins: "for n in sequence:"

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm wondering what the technical description is of the variable `n` in a `for` loop that begins `for n in sequence`. I suppose my question is about nomenclature. Would it be accurate to say that it's a temporary named variable that gets discarded upon conclusion of the loop? I suspect that there's a canonical way of referring to it. Thanks!

Comment: It's a variable and it's not discarded at the end of a loop.

Comment: No. It's an ordinary variable in whatever the containing scope is. It's _exactly_ the same as a name you used as `n = 123`. for loops do not introduce a new scope in Python.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you are looking for? The `n` here has both a syntactical and semantic meaning, and one might see it differently for example in contrast to assignment (`n = 2`), complex targets (`for n[m] in b:`) or target lists (`for n, m in b:`).

Comment: @Matthias oh wow! I've been coding for 6 years and I don't think I've ever noticed this. I had to test it just now. I learned something really important today. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an ordinary variable, which happens to be the target of an assignment. What assignment? The assignment of a value produced by the `__next__` method of the iterator being traversed by the loop.

Every `for` loop of the form

```
for <var> in <iterable>:
    ...
```

could be transformed into an equivalent `while` loop.

```
_itr = iter(<iterable>)
while True:
    try:
        <var> = next(_itr)  # Here's the assignment
    except StopIteration:
        break
    ...
del _itr
```

`<var>` is not discarded after the loop completes. (The temporary variable `_itr` is, but it's *truly* an implementation detail of the `for` loop, not something that was ever visible to the Python code.)

Like any other assignment, `<var>` is defined the first time it is assigned to, and it lives until the end of the scope where it was defined or until it is removed with a `del` statement).

Answer (score 1):

In the example:

```
for n in [1,2,3]:
   print(n)

print(n)
```

The output would be:

```
1
2
3
3
```

I.e. `n` is a regular variable that is created in the `for...` line. It takes the value of each item in the sequence as you go through the loop.

And after the for loop is completed, the `n` variable remains with the last value that it was assigned (i.e. the last value in the sequence unless you break out of the for loop early)

Comment: Lol this is amazing and I can't believe I'm just learning that n persists after termination of the loop.

Comment: @NaiveBae, It's a behavior that is probably more apparent when you work in Jupyter notebooks a lot. It can often be a useful "feature" to check that everything in the loop is working as expected (e.g. you can add a `break` in there and check that the first iteration is doing what you expect before letting it run the full for loop).